# Nuxt.js, How to add Sitemap.xml to the dynamic routes?

Tags: vue.js, nuxt.js

I am using Nuxt.js `nuxt/sitemap` module, Everything works fine, but my goal is to prioritize dynamic routes

```js
//nuxt.config.js

  /* sitemap XML */
    sitemap: {
      hostname: 'example.com',
      gzip: true,
      exclude: [
        '/user/**',
        '/admin/**',
        '/user',
        '/admin',
        '/booking',
        '/sales',
        '/payment',
        '/payment/**',
        '/search-result'
      ],
      routes:async () => {
        const { data } = await axios.get('/api/book')
        return data.data.map((product) =>`/product/${product.id}`)
      },
      
    },
```

This is current `XML` data which I am recieving

[image]

But my aim is to add `<lastmod>`, `<changefreq>`, `<priority>` properties to existing `<loc>` property, like picture below

[image]

How can I achieve this?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can add a `defaults` property to the `sitemap` config object:

```js
sitemap: {
    defaults: {
      changefreq: 'daily',
      priority: 1,
      lastmod: '2023-02-25'
    }
  }
```

Comment: -1. This is actually a terrible SEO practice. You should only change the <lastmod /> property when there is a significant change in content you're serving. Given this is executed every time you build your Nuxt application, [search engines will eventually begin ignoring your <lastmod>](https://developers.google.com/search/blog/2023/06/sitemaps-lastmod-ping#the-lastmod-element). As for the defaults, route settings cannot override them in Nuxt, which makes your sitemap uncustomizable.

Comment: @Endermanch Thanks for the comment. I have removed that property now, and that can be set using some logic to test if the page being rendered has been updated or not.